# book suggestion about differential geometry

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry

Could someone suggest me a good book to start differential geometry which is not
very hard to start with? I have learnt several variable calculus in the previous
semester but haven't yet read any stuff about differential geometry.

Comment: Spivak is a classic.

Answer (score 0):

A standard reference is Manfredo P. Do Carmo's *Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces*. If I remember correctly, the only pre-requisite is multivariable calculus.